# How to specify path in Python to save audiofiles

Tags: python, path

this code records and saves a .wav file. 
I´ve tried to set a path where my files can be saved.
But nothing I tried seems to work.

This is my code:

```
import time
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

def recording(seconds):  
    fs = 44100  # Sample rate

    myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
    sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
    write('C:\Users\****\Desktop\AudioFiles\output1.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file 

def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timeformat = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timeformat, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    print('Aufnahme beendet!\n\n\n\n\n')

print('Stimme wird aufgenommen.')

sec = 3   # Duration of recording
recording(sec)  
countdown(sec)
```

And this is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-d2b5ec707d01>", line 10
    write('C:\Users\****\Desktop\Neuer Ordner (2)\output1.wav', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

If I try this code without a path it works. `write('output.wav', fs, myrecording)`

Comment: Use a raw string `r'...'`. Otherwise the backslashes may be interpreted as start of an escape sequence.

Comment: Thank you! It works